# How to do Aggregation in Node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am currently finding out ways to do Aggregation in Node js. I have tried to do $lts, $gte and others but im wondering if these are all categorized as aggregation or not. If not, can you please enlighten me a little. Below is what i have. Can i have an example of how to do an aggregation of $sum or $average.

$gte

```
db.contact.find("machine_unit" : {$gte:5}}, function(err,meibanlist){
  if (err || !meibanlist ) console.log("Record is not found");
else meibanlist.forEach (function(machine_unit){
console.log(machine_unit);
});
});
```

Comment: maybe [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_aggregation.htm) will help.

Comment: read some tutorials on aggregation man, there are a plenty of them out there.

Comment: Plenty of examples for aggregation out there on MongoDB driver [Reference](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/) & [API](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/) documentation! Pls read the docs before asking.

Answer (score 1):

The following example demonstrates an aggregate operation in a node.js express app where a REST API endpoint returns a list of documents from the aggregation which calculates the average and document count in a single **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline.

The aggregation operation uses the **[`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)** function which takes in a pipeline denoted by an array to group all the documents in the collection on the `machine_Id` key and returns the total number of documents per group as well as the average amount (that is, if the document has an `amount` field):

```
app.get('/meibanlist/machines', function (req, res) {
    db.meibanlist.aggregate([
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$machine_Id",
                "count": { "$sum": 1 },
                "average": { "$avg": "$amount" }
            }
        }
    ], function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        res.json(result);
    });
});
```